# Windows that are snapped to one side freeze the computer when I drag them to make them full screen

Tags: unity, snap-windows

When I have a window snapped to one side, and I drag it to the top of the screen to make it go full screen, it displays the area that it will be, stops at about 4/5s of the way there, and freezes the computer, forcing me to reboot to start using anything. Sometimes it doesn't do this, but most of the time it does. What is going on?

Comment: What desktop manager are you using? GNOME, Unity, KDE, etc...

Comment: Unity. Aside from installed applications, I'm basically running vanilla Ubuntu.

Comment: Try GNOME, as it can be generally less (and sometimes more) annoying. When you say it freezes, can you enter the [tty](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=833765) (command line interface with the computer), move the mouse, or anything? Updating may also help, due to bug fixes.

Comment: If trying GNOME (works pretty much the same as Unity), you will need to install it, using [Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto), [apt-get](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) or any other sort of package manager

Answer (score 1):

This is [bug #1244754](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1244754).

The workaround is to use shortcut keys *Ctrl + Super + Up* to maximise windows.

Comment: Bug has been reported fixed as of 17.02.2014.